# How do I find and call the kube-apiserver in k3s / k3d (with Calico and without it)?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, k3s, kube-apiserver, k3d

I want to use the `kube-apiserver` to enable/disable admission controllers *(e.g. `kube-apiserver --enable-admission-plugins=NamespaceLifecycle`)*, but I cannot find it anywhere.

When I run the following, I don't see it anywhere:

```sh
# Running this:
kubectl get pods -n kube-system

# Shows only this:
# NAME                                       READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
# helm-install-traefik-fvs4z                 0/1     Completed   0          10d
# local-path-provisioner-5ff76fc89d-rrntw    1/1     Running     4          10d
# coredns-854c77959c-vz4s2                   1/1     Running     4          10d
# metrics-server-86cbb8457f-6kl5n            1/1     Running     4          10d
# svclb-traefik-cc7zx                        2/2     Running     8          10d
# calico-kube-controllers-5dc5c9f744-6bwdj   1/1     Running     4          10d
# calico-node-xcjz8                          1/1     Running     4          10d
# traefik-6f9cbd9bd4-b6nk7                   1/1     Running     4          10d
```

I thought it might be due to using Calico, but even creating a cluster without Calico still shows no `kube-apiserver`:

```sh
# Running this:
kubectl get pods -n kube-system

# Shows only this:
# NAME                                      READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
# local-path-provisioner-5ff76fc89d-d28gc   1/1     Running     0          2m31s
# coredns-854c77959c-lh78n                  1/1     Running     0          2m31s
# metrics-server-86cbb8457f-xlzl2           1/1     Running     0          2m31s
# helm-install-traefik-nhxp4                0/1     Completed   0          2m31s
# svclb-traefik-hqndx                       2/2     Running     0          2m21s
# traefik-6f9cbd9bd4-m42jg                  1/1     Running     0          2m21s
```

Where is the `kube-apiserver`? How do I enable and disable controllers in k3d?

Answer (score 0):

It's not running via static pod, so it doesn't show up as a pod. With k3s you would usually install it as a systemd service unit. With k3d you can see it via `docker ps`.

Comment: How would I call it? Do I `exec` into that docker container? And which one is it? I see two: `rancher/k3d-proxy:v4.4.1` and `rancher/k3s:v1.20.5-k3s1`

Comment: When I exec into both of those, e.g. `docker exec -it k3d-dev-server-0 /bin/sh` I get a terminal, but when I type `kube-apiserver` both containers say `/bin/sh: kube-apiserver: not found`

Comment: I don't understand your question, you don't call anything and I don't think they include a shell in the container as its a single-purpose daemon. It's just a thing that is running. You configure it through its config file, though I'm not actually sure how much of admission plugins are configurable, you would have to check their docs.

Comment: You can call the admission controller to enable/disable controllers/plugins. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/ For example, `kube-apiserver --disable-admission-plugins=PodNodeSelector,AlwaysDeny`. How would I do that in k3d?

Comment: That's not a "call", it's not a stateful thing. You have to include that on the command line when it starts. Every time.

Comment: So I can't disable them after it's already running?

Comment: Correct. You would have to change the CLI arguments in whatever config file they live in and restart kube-apiserver.

Answer (score 0):

For people coming by and searching for answer:

K3s runs all control-plane components in a single systemd process. If you need to add extra arguments to one of them, you need to pass through the `k3s.service`.

For your example, in order to enable/disable admission controllers :

1. add the following line to this file `/etc/systemd/system/k3s.service`

```
    --server-arg=--kube-apiserver-arg=enable-admission-plugins=NamespaceLifecycle
```

2. restart control-plane

> you may have disruption if you're not on HA mode.

```
systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart k3
```

3. check logs to verify if everything is okey `systemctl logs k3s.service`

Hope it helps.

references:

- https://docs.k3s.io/cli/server#k3s-server-cli-help
- https://docs.k3s.io/architecture#servers-and-agents